# How to bind to a Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, .net-3.5, textbox

my XAML is

```
<TextBox Name="DutchName" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding customer,Path=DutchName }" />
```

my class is

```
class customer
{
    Name name;
}

class Name
{
    string DutchName;
    string EnglishName;
}
```

The `TextBox` is not bound.
Can anyone correct this error please?

Thanks,

Comment: you need to edit your post and make the code highlighted (use the 101010 button)

Answer (score 5):

i dont think your code would compile for starters,

should be

```
public class customer
{
    public Name name { get; set; }
}

public class Name
{
    public string DutchName { get; set; }
    public string EnglishName { get; set; }
}
```

this will enable you to **get once** and **set** the properties from xaml, however if you set the properties in code you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged (otherwise your user interface wont know). From your question i think you need to do a little more study. find out about these topics. (to start with)

- Properties
- Accessors (public, private,
  protected, internal) - you cant bind to a non public property
- INotifyPropertyChanged

your xaml binding should look like this

```
<TextBox  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=name.DutchName }" />
```

if you set the data context of the window/user control you are working in to be the customer. e.g.

```
....
InitializeComponent();

customer cust = new customer();
cust.Name = new Name { DutchName = "Sigfried", EnglishName = "Roy" };
this.DataContext = cust;
....
```

Comment: +1 good answer, saved me having to write anything - i just hope @jjjou bothers to mark it.

Comment: +1, although I'm surprised to see that Sigfried is the Dutch version of "Roy" :)

Comment: these dutch translations get the uninitiated every time :) I'm betting he wont mark it tho....sigh